# How to select within one column where the fields are similar

Tags: sql

I'm using sql... I have a table name Table1 with 2 columns: column1 and column2. First i need to select both columns where column 1 contains "andrew" or "brandon". Then i want to compare within column2 and return the results for strings that are similar for the fields within column2.

```
column1 column2
andrew  hi
brandon hello
andrew  hello
carl    hi
```

return:

```
brandon hello
andrew  hello
```

Comment: The second part is not very clear. Can you elaborate? So far, I see that you want the values of column2 which are common for "andrew" and "brandon". Also which database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to compare two rows, you can't really get away without a JOIN or subquery. If I understand you correctly, this should do what you want in "any database" SQL;

```
SELECT t1a.* 
FROM Table1 t1a 
JOIN Table1 t1b
  ON t1a.column2 = t1b.column2 AND t1a.column1 <> t1b.column1
WHERE t1a.column1 in ('andrew', 'brandon') AND 
      t1b.column1 IN ('andrew', 'brandon');
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/33232/1).

Answer (score 0):

Try with following query:

```
SELECT column1+' '+ column2 from Table1  where column1 IN ('andrew','brandon')
```